# OpenCV getting very slow when using cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the following code to create a simple video player but I've seen that when I introduce the
`cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,arg)` line, the all process is getting very slow while playing the video. The player works correctly with its trackbar but the speed is very slow.
In general I noted that every time you use the `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,...)` command the speed get much slower than leaving the player going with `ret, frame = cap.read()` without setting the framenumber
I need to use the cv2 because the purpose of job is to treat all frames by overlapping a text to every frame and show on the player (the text overlay code is not yet written here)

```
import cv2
    
    
def on_trackbar(arg):
    global cap
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,arg)

    filevideo = r'D:\Documenti\Regate\Progetti\VideoOverlayData\Sviluppo\VideoOverlayData\INPUTFILES\28AugRace5.MP4'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filevideo)
    Videofps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    nr_of_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
            print("Error opening video stream or file")
            
    cv2.namedWindow('Frame', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
    cv2.createTrackbar("F", "Frame", 0, nr_of_frames, on_trackbar)
    videoCurrentFrameNumber = 0
    while(cap.isOpened()):
           # cap.set(1,videoCurrentFrameNumber)
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret is True:
                cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)
                videoCurrentFrameNumber = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
                #cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,videoCurrentFrameNumber)
                #cap.set(5,50)
                cv2.setTrackbarPos('F','Frame',videoCurrentFrameNumber)
                #videoCurrentFrameNumber = videoCurrentFrameNumber +1
                frameclick = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if frameclick == ord('q'):
                       break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When you removed the *Videofps* line, the result still same?

Comment: yes it's the same, the Videofps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) is not the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure your OpenCV build is missing FFMPEG support.
Rebuild it with it. If you're using vcpkg, then you need this one: "opencv4[ffmpeg]"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using `python3` with `opencv-python 4.5.5.64` on an m1 mac. ( [Last known version to work with trackbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869207/5655414), as of writing this article ) The [best explanation](https://forum.opencv.org/t/why-is-capture-set-cv2-cap-prop-pos-frames-i-so-slow/4886) i've found is that random access it is naturally slow. Though, I recall using older versions of opencv-python with your code with absolutely no problem. Needless to say, the solution that made **most sense to my case** was to load the entire video into memory and then display it. The code for my use-case is shown below, where I've build a video player with frame by frame (`a`,`b`) movement and play/pause (`spacebar`). The default position is pause:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime
import os
import sys

# import the video
videoFile = sys.argv[1];

# load capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

# prepare view
view_name = "Video in memory"
total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
cv2.namedWindow(view_name)
cv2.createTrackbar('S',view_name, 0,int(total_frames)-1, lambda x:x)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('S',view_name,0)

# read the entire video to memory
print("[INFO] loading frames to memory")
all_frames = []
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frame_exists, frame = cap.read()
    if frame_exists == True:
        all_frames.append(frame)
    else:
        break

# When everything done, release the video capture object
cap.release()
print("[INFO] load compelte");

# set default play state to pause
status = 'pause'
previous_status = 'pause'
frame_idx = 0
while True:
    try:
        if frame_idx==total_frames-1:
            frame_idx=0

        frame = all_frames[frame_idx]
        cv2.imshow(view_name,frame)

        # event handling
        keyPress = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if keyPress & 0xFF == ord(' '):
            status = 'play_pause_click'
        elif keyPress & 0xFF == ord('a'):
            status = 'prev_frame'
        elif keyPress & 0xFF == ord('d'):
            status = 'next_frame'
        elif keyPress & 0xFF == -1:
            status = status
        elif keyPress & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            status = 'exit'

        if (status == 'play_pause_click' and previous_status == 'play_pause_click'):
            status = 'pause'
            previous_status = 'pause'
        if (status == 'play_pause_click'):
            status = 'play'
            previous_status = 'play_pause_click'

        if status == 'play':
            frame_idx += 1
            cv2.setTrackbarPos('S',view_name,frame_idx)
            continue
        if status == 'pause':
            frame_idx = cv2.getTrackbarPos('S',view_name)
        if status=='prev_frame':
            frame_idx-=1
            frame_idx = max(0, frame_idx)
            cv2.setTrackbarPos('S',view_name,frame_idx)
            status='pause'
        if status=='next_frame':
            frame_idx+=1
            cv2.setTrackbarPos('S',view_name,frame_idx)
            status='pause'
        if status == 'exit':
            break

    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid Key was pressed")
 
# Closes the generated window
cv2.destroyWindow(view_name)
```